# Make 3 Divs float and align horizontal at 33% Width 5% Padding

Tags: html, css

I need 3 divs with Width: 33% and Padding: 5% to sit alongside each other.
Float left and display: block;

My solution doesn't keep it on the same vertical line:

```
div {
float: left;
display: block;
background-color: gray;
width: 33%;
padding:5%;
border-radius: 1px;
border-style: solid;
```

[image]

Whatever makes it sit next to each other regardless if 99%+15% isn't 100%!

Comment: Three divs at 33% add up to 99% of the width. Then you throw in 5% padding and a border so figure it out.

Comment: `width: 28%` 
`padding: 5%`?

Comment: As @Rob pointed out, your math is wrong. Padding is taken into account when setting box size, UNLESS, you set `box-sizing: border-box` on  your div. Then the padding is included *in* your width.

Comment: If you use flexbox and `flex-grow` the elements, it will evenly size them for you automatically

Comment: @Jay it would need to be 23%, since it's 5% on all sides (so a total of 10% for left and right)

Comment: @disinfor you're good, but I think @PatMan10's solution is actually best here, use `justify-content: space-evenly` instead of manually specifying `width` with percent

Comment: I agree! I think `flex-box` is the way, just more pointing out the math :)

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's a trick question by my teacher, a lot in class are wondering what the H he means, I added that so you'd know but, moderators don't want excess stuff I guess.

Again I'm not stupid, I'm just trying to figure out if it is actually possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a flex-box example to steer you in the right direction.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
   background-color: cyan;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   height: 100vh;
 }

 .container > div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 1%;
  }

  .red{ background-color: red; }
  .yellow{ background-color: yellow; }
  .green{ background-color: green; }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   <div class="red">red</div>
   <div class="yellow">yellow</div>
   <div class="green">green</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the best solution for this, however for the sake a simplicity (and because a flex-box based answer has already been given) you can use `display: inline-block;` to get them inline and `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the padding *within* the block;

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#wrapper {
  background: blue;
}

.box {
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
  Padding:  0;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <div class="box left">box left</div>
  <div class="box right">box right </div>
  <div class="box">box middle </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer does not address the `padding`, nor does it actually work.

Comment: Also, floats are horrible

Comment: Please refrain from answering with only code. Instead, [edit] the question to contain an explanation on how it works, either in text around, or comments within the code. Remember that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of this question. See [answer]